Not able to run on the ios device flutter app
I am trying to run my flutter app on ios but I am facing some issues.
code build done.                                           63.3s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **
2

Xcode's output:
↳
    Writing result bundle at path:
        /var/folders/4h/3lxr2wd15j975kxm6f3sz9nr0000gn/T/flutter_tools.lQjnn0/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirjQJlCd/temporary_xcresult_bundle

    /Users/mac/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/url_launcher_ios-6.3.0/ios/url_launcher_ios/Sources/url_launcher_ios/Launcher.swift:22:1: error: type 'UIApplication' does not conform to protocol 'Launcher'
    extension UIApplication: Launcher {}
    ^
    UIKit.UIApplication:24:15: note: candidate has non-matching type '(URL, [UIApplication.OpenExternalURLOptionsKey : Any], (@MainActor @Sendable (Bool) -> Void)?) -> Void'
        open func open(_ url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenExternalURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:], completionHandler completion: (@MainActor @Sendable (Bool) -> Void)? = nil)
                  ^
    /Users/mac/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/url_launcher_ios-6.3.0/ios/url_launcher_ios/Sources/url_launcher_ios/Launcher.swift:22:1: note: add stubs for conformance
    extension UIApplication: Launcher {}
    ^


I try to clear the pod files and flutter clean.

Have you tried repairing your pub-cache?  dart pub cache repair and then you'll have to run flutter pub get in your projects.

This could be due to many reasons. First thing you can try is upadating url_launcher if it’s not the latest versin.
If updating url_launcher doesn’t solve your issue, then you can try updating Flutter and Xcode to the latest version.
After upgrading flutter version, run command flutter pub upgrade

I can't update the flutter version, I need to run on the same version which I having now. I am using the url_launcher 6.3.0

Share your configuration like OS, Flutter SDK, Xcode version, Xcode command line tools version etc. You can add in your main question post.
